# How to change "select country for visa" in CGI Federal Schedule appointment

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

My friend is now staying in foreign nation and was trying to apply for US visa from the same nation where she is staying now so she paid visa fee from there but when she tried to schedule the appointment then got to know that she had put wrong name in select country for visa while making account in CGI federal. So how could she change the name in select country for visa to the one she is staying now.